# reducing redundancy in TypeScript exports

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

Each of the TypeScript files in a `models` directory exports a main type and a collection of methods that are related to it.

```
export type User = { ... }

export function addToTeam() { ... }
```

I'm re-exporting all of these files through an `index.ts` at the root of the directory.

```
import * as User from "./User";
import * as Team from "./Team";

export { User, Team };
```

This adds some redundancy when referring to the main type around the rest of the codebase.

```
import { User, Team } from "./models";

function join(user: User.User, team: Team.Team) {
  return User.addToTeam(user.id, team.id);
}
```

Seeing as types and values don't live in the same scope, it's possible to export both under the same name.

```
// models/index.ts
import * as _User from "./User";
import * as _Team from "./Team";

export const User = _User;
export type User = _User.User;

export const Team = _Team;
export type Team = _Team.Team;
```

Which means the imported identifier can refer to both.

```
import { User, Team } from "./models";

function join(user: User, team: Team) {
  return Foo.createFoo(foo);
}
```

Is there any way to export both under the same name without creating a new type and and a new variable in the process?

Here are some examples of unsuccessful attempts.

```
// TypeScript doesn't support "export * as"
export * as User from "./User";
export { User } from "./User";

// Duplicate exports
import * as User from "./User";
export type User = User.User;
export { User };

// Duplicate exports
import * as User from "./User";
import { User as UserType } from "./User";
export { User, UserType as User }

// Duplicate exports
import * as User from "./User";
export { User } from "./User";
export { User };
```

The main problem with all of the above that the `export { ... }` form seems to export in both type and value scopes.

Here are some other workarounds that I'm not interested in:

- Wrapping the functions in a namespace with the same name as the type
- Changing the *exported* name of the type
- Using a typed class with static methods

Comment: I'm curious about a few things. (1) what kind of dependencies/arguments do those associated functions take? They look similar to database operations, which personally, would make me more inclined to group them via a class, like a `UsersRepository`.(2) I think storing the functions in the `/models` directory is a bit confusing, since `/models` typically only includes things like interfaces, types, enums, etc. (3) Why use a type instead of an interface for the `User`?

Comment: @christian 1) Sure, database operations is exactly what they are. Some people like using a repository pattern in a class, some people like keeping operations as functions. Both have advantages and disadvantages, I prefer functions. 2) Not sure where this idea comes from. That's not a pattern I've ever heard of before! 3) I like that you can use `type` to express lots of ideas (unions, intersections, aliases, functions, objects), there's nothing wrong with `interface` but I don't often make use of their main selling points (e.g inheritance), therefore I don't often use them.

Answer (score -1):

In index.ts you should be able to just export from module... no need to import it first.

```
import * as User from "./User";
import * as Team from "./Team";

export { User, Team };
```

Change to:

```
export * from "./User";
export * from "./Team";
```

Than you will be able to remove these redundant names:

```
import { User, Team } from "./models";

function join(user: User, team: Team) {
  return addToTeam(user.id, team.id);
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few problems with this. The main one is collisions across exported names (e.g. there is a `findById` export in both `User.ts` and `Team.ts`).

This has a ripple effect on the implicit context that came from hierarchy (e.g `User.findById` now has to be renamed to `findUserById`).

It also means that every single model function needs to be imported separately (e.g. `import { addToTeam } from "./models"`) or imported all at once (e.g. `import * as models from "./models";`.